# How to include large set of data with my iOS app at install?

Tags: ios, plist

I have a big database of data I want my app to install with, too big for NSDefaults, essentially it's too big for me to type in (it's computer generated).

I can easily serialize it into a hierarchial NSDictionary format and a pList, but I'm stumped on how to get that pList from my running app into a file that Xcode will include in app builds, and where to install it, etc.

I've tried dumping my pLists out with .description to try to just copy and paste them into an Xcode .plist file. But pList.description outputs in the format

```
Problem8 = {
Term1 = 3;
};
```

While the Plist files in Xcode require a format like

```
<key>Problem8</key>
<string>3</string>
<key>Term1</key>
```

Feeling pretty dumb here, I'm obviously missing something easy to get to the correct format, or to save them serialized to disc in a manner that Xcode will include in future builds.

Comment: One problem with the generated data is that I can't regenerate it for the user, as it's got some random values that would make it different if regenerated. I want this data set identical for every user (the data describes the introductory levels for a game), so I need to include this data as file or pList/etc at installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dictionary, use `writeToFile:atomically:` to save it to a file and `initWithContentsOfFile:` to load it back in.

That said, if it's a lot of data, and particularly if you don't need all of it loaded all the time, consider saving a Core Data store and deploying that.

Comment: I understand how to do that. But how to I make that file part of my installation package for my app in Xcode so it's included in my app submission/TestFlight distributions/etc?

Comment: Add the file to a copy files build phase (like images are added into the build).

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, I run the app on my device/simulator, generate the file to it's local sandbox, and use the organizer to download a copy to my mac's file system, and copy the data file from there into my project? Thanks for your comments, greatly appreciate you taking time to help me through this.

Comment: Yes. Or you can have a desktop app which generates the file instead. If the app can generate it then why deploy with a big file?